# Choose to query multiple tables with radio buttons using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm building a comics website, which has two subsites: Comics and Artwork. Comics and Artwork are stored in two separate tables.

I have a search function that allows the user to search for an image.

I'd like to give them an option to choose to search for only comics, only artwork, or both.

[image]

I have the following **javascript** which I believe should be working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function search(searchString) {     
           var site = $("#site").val();
           $.get("./scripts/search.php", {_input : searchString, _site : site},
                function(returned_data) {
                    $("#output").html(returned_data);
                }
            );
        }

        function searchChoice(choice) {     
           $.get("./scripts/search.php", {_choice : choice}
           );
        }

</script>
```

And the following HTML:

```
    <!--Search filtering for comics, artwork, or both-->
<span class="search"><b>Search for: </b> </span>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<span class="search">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="comics" onclick="searchChoice(this.id)">Comics</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="artwork" onclick="searchChoice(this.id)">Artwork</button> 
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="all" onclick="searchChoice(this.id)">All</button> 
</span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<!--Search functionality-->
<span class="search">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value)" name="input" value="" />
    <input id="site" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $site; ?>">
</span>

<br />
<span id="output"><span class="sidebarimages">  </span></span>
```

My question is here with the **PHP** in querying TWO tables:

**Am I doing the JOIN correctly?**

```
$input = (isset($_GET['_input']) ? ($_GET['_input']) : 0); 
$choice = (isset($_GET['_choice']) ? ($_GET['_choice']) : "all");
$site = (isset($_GET['site']) ? ($_GET['site']) : null);


if ($choice == "artwork") {
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, thumb FROM artwork";
    $thumbpath = "./images/Artwork/ArtThumbnails/";
}
else if ($choice == "comics") {
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, thumb FROM comics";
    $thumbpath = "./images/Comics/ComicThumbnails/";
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, thumb FROM comics 
            UNION 
            SELECT id, title, thumb FROM artwork";
    $thumbpath = "./images/AllThumbnails/";
}


$imgpaths = $mysqli->query($sql);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to specify what field(s) to join on, if you do indeed want to join.  I'd recommend just running 2 select statements.  I also don't see any `where` clause, which means you'll return everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not stating any conditions for joining the 2 tables, also in the case of looking in both tables, you may want to consider using `UNION` instead, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM comics
UNION
SELECT * FROM artwork
```

Comment: Hey I've edited my PHP sql statement above. The search seems to always be defaulting to the last else statement (query both comics and artwork) even though I've selected comics.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the expected value on `$choice`?

Comment: "alert("Choice: " + choice)" alerts out the correct choice ("comics", "artwork", or "all" based on choice)... so I know the correct option is coming into the javascript

Comment: But for some reason, when I go to the PHP script and echo out "choice", it's echoing out "all" for comics, artwork, and all cases. Not sure why the selected value isn't properly coming into the php file

Answer (score 2):

To use JOIN function you need relations between tables (foreign keys connecting one to another)

Comment: Hey I've edited my PHP sql statement above. The search is returning both comics and artwork even though I've chosen just comics. Any idea why?